# Fill Lookup field within workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow

**Problem:**
I have 1 list and 1 document library. I want to automatically create a folder in the document library for each list item in the list. Then a lookup field named "Activity Documents" in the list item should point to the created folder in the document library.

**Question:**
How can I do this in a workflow (SharePoint 2010 / SharePoint Designer 2010) that runs automatically when a new list item is created?

Currently I am ready to create the folder, but the workflow does not fill the lookup field... it just stays empty.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you can create columns or set Lookup Column sources with workflows. You will probably need to resort to JavaScript to get this done. Try looking at this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209228/sharepoint-2013-javascript-insert-item-with-lookup-field